# how to incorporate html files in an app

Tags: iphone

I have a objective c app that is a universal. I want for the ipad view, to be able to load some items (from a tableview) to be html files that are stored locally. I don't want to add a new separate library like phonegap. So what I'm trying to do, in case I wasn't clear, is to not use phonegap, but use apple functions to be able to load a web page locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to user UIWebViews. You can either give a UIWebView a file via URL (you can get a URL to a local file via `[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html]` )
or you can give it a string to show. Have a look at the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes, it will work for css, images and the like if the paths are all relative. And you'll have to start with one html file or build views for each one if you have multiple